# fetching all entries from database under a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am fetching all rows from the database when the status is 1.

It isn't working properly. If the first entry status is equal to 1, then it will fetch all data from the database even when their statuses are not 1. And if the first entry status is not 1 but the rest are, it does not fetch.

```
$status = $mysqli->query("SELECT status FROM Overrides WHERE professor = '$name'")->fetch_object()->status;
```

then code i wish to restrict to status 1 is put under:

```
if ($status == 1) {
```

Is it something that i should add to the above code?

Comment: `i'm fetching all rows from the database when the status is 1` I don't see anything that should limit it to rows where the statis is 1.

Comment: `fetch_object()` returns one row at a time in order. Generally in cases like this you'd use a loop to iterate over each row, also, what @Mike said.

Comment: @Mike fixed i did a mistake.

Comment: based on your statement the query will be  $status = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Overrides WHERE status = '1'"); rest of i don't know, why you use

Comment: The point of queries is to return the data you need. If you only want the rows with `status = 1` then that should be in the query. It wastes resources to retrieve data from the database to just discard in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand, but:

- Put all results in an array and iterate it and get all you need.
- Or do 2 or 3 querys.
- Or iterate results in while fetch and break if the first is not your condition.

If you use mysqli, you can use prepared statement to prevent injection "'$name'" is dangerous and ugly.

Comment: Not *everyone* has an ugly name... :(